# An iOS app for JIRA that works

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, applications

I am a Jira superuser, my company runs Jira and I am looking for a way to use it on the go.
Unfortunately, none of the mobile Jira app I have been using seems to work with our setup.

Does anyone have recommendations?

Comment: Which apps have you tried already?

Comment: I think Jira Anywhere Jira Touch Bugbox

none of them were working on our Jira 4

Comment: Can you provide more detail on what features you need it to provide?

Comment: Update tickets assigned to me mostly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At present, the best mobile app for JIRA may well be Mobile Safari. Have you tried installing Atlassian's [JIRA iPhone Web Interface](https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/16089?versionId=21712) plug-in?

**EDIT (based on subsequent comments):**
It seems like you've tried most of the available apps. The only one I haven't tried is Undock - it's $5, but it supports Gemini, Basecamp, and Bugzilla as well as JIRA. Has great reviews, so it might be worth a shot.

Failing that, they do have the JIRA plug-in source code on Bitbucket. Updating it to JIRA 5 would be pretty difficult but I bet updating from 4.2.4 to 4.3 would not be too bad.

Comment: I will try asap! Thx.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not compatible with our version of Jira (4.3) :-(

Comment: Well, it seems like you've tried most of the apps. The only one I haven't tried is Undock - it's $5, but it supports Gemini, Basecamp, and Bugzilla as well as JIRA.  Has great reviews, so it might be worth a shot.  ailing that, they do have the plug-in source code on Bitbucket. Updating it to JIRA 5 would be pretty difficult but I bet updating from 4.2.4 to 4.3 would not be too bad.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Undock seems like working... I think it handles well SSL (which was one of my issues) however it seems very very slow and I have a lot of "Network Problems" messages. I'll try it more to see if it can be usable. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Free iOS app for JIRA was released in March and there are a lots of features coming on mobile.Here is the link to official JIRA app, [JIRA Mobile](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/jira-software/id1006972087?mt=8)

Answer (score 0):

Here is nice free one officially from Atlassian: [JIRA Real Life](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/jira-real-life/id528455730?mt=8)

It allows you to quickly add issues on the go with voice notes, photos.
Handy to add issues, but I guess it is not for browsing through existing issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can try also JIRA.me application. We have released it 2 months ago ([Pro version](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/jira.me-pro/id703802938?ls=1&mt=8)) and just recently we've published a [Free, read-only](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/jira.me/id741586049?ls=1&mt=8) version (you can buy Pro upgrade later) that allows you to get what the application is like.

A quick summary of current functionality:

- pre-defined and user defined (through Web interface) filters available,
- inline actions like assign directly from issues list, or issue details
- editing an issue,
- searching for issues
- supports Confluence Wiki markup language

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Be sure to read the help section about [self-promotion](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) and include a disclaimer for any software that you are affiliated with.

Answer (score 0):

Check out our new iOS JIRA App: [Chronoscope for JIRA](http://chronoscope.diso.ch)

Some of the features included are:

- track your working time with the included stopwatch (chronoscope)
- work on multiple JIRA systems simultaneously
- browse the cockpit for a very fast access to your tasks
- get an overview of all your work logs
- search for specific issues

Soon we are going to release a new version with a timesheet (looks like a calendar with all your worklogs).

Answer (score 0):

JIRA Board offers a nice, native way to visualize your kanban & scrum boards

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/jira-board-kanban-scrum-agile/id934196108?mt=8

Answer (score 0):

[Easy Jira](https://itunes.apple.com/app/apple-store/id1122988139?pt=221455&ct=StackExchange&mt=8) is an iPhone app designed as an alternative to Atlassian's mobile client. Just as Atlassian's "JIRA Cloud" it is simple to use, but has some unique differences:

- The app works with self-hosted JIRA servers
- There is no "your session timed out" problem. App simply logs you in
  automatically. The auto-login can be secured by fingerprint
  verification if needed
- Caching mechanism inside the app allows you to access tasks while
  offline (in read-only mode)
- Unlike all other iPhone clients, the app allows you to attach any
  possible files to JIRA (not only images and videos)

The app is designed to work with custom workflows. If you find any problems with your JIRA workflow - write me (I'm the developer of this app) and I will try to make respective corrections in the engine.

The file uploading functionality is paid, but the rest 99% of the app is free to use.

[image]

http://easyjira.in.ua